# Windows 7 user profile migration between domains + exchange

Tags: windows-7, domain, outlook

I'll spare the long winded explanation as to why, let's just say the company has had a massive change and I'm taking the opportunity to perform some infrastructure changes.

I have several 2003 servers, the AD functional level is 2003. My exchange server is 2003. The exchange server is currently not accepting emails, it's all been diverted to a off-site basic mail server.

I'm creating a new forest + domain, 2012 server, 2012 functional level. I also want to install a fresh version of Exchange 2013. I have no need to migrate users or mailboxes from the 2003 system to the 2012 domain.

I'm not going to upgrade all the servers, most will remain on 2003 for the short to medium term. Will this cause any issues? (They'll only be domain members)

What is important however is that the users outlook profiles are retained locally. 
The locally downloaded email, calendar, contacts and notes. The users have all this already in an OST on their laptops.

The Windows 7 profiles I'd like to copy also between the domain switch also, but this not as important as outlook.

A lot of the guides and resources I'm reading cover the server migration which I'm not interested in.

What would be the best way of migrating the user profile and outlook profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll export the OST file into a PST and import it into the new Outlook profile.

As for the user profile itself...and possibly the Outlook profile/OST, but I wouldn't trust associating an OST file with a new user...you can use Profwiz by ForensiT...just google it.  That's my recommendation if you want to keep the profile.

Answer (score 0):

The profile migration can be done according to this article: http://blog.raido.be/?p=297. I assume there is a domain trust in your environment, then you can copy the files and registry settings according to the description in the article. The article uses AppSense to do the copy, but this can just as easily be done with a logonscript.

Comment: Link-rot happens, so please include at least a summary of the procedure outlined in linked content.